# JavaScript access anchor in list

Tags: javascript, html, iteration

Currently my code iterates through each `<li>` within a `<td>` cell and applies a class to the `<li>`. I've now added `<a>` tags in between each `<li>` and am having problems accessing the `<a>`. I essentially want to add a class to each `<a>` tag rather than the `<li>`.

**HTML**

```
<td style='padding: 0;' bgcolor='#FAFAFA'>
    <ul class='doctorList'>
        <li id='1'><a style='text-decoration: none;'>Curly</a></li>
        <li id='2'>Larry</li>
        <li id='3'>Moe</li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function mapBookedAppointmentsToCalendar()
{
    var bookedAppointmentsArray = <?php echo json_encode($mappingIdArray) ?>;
    var table = document.getElementById("tbl_calendar");

    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
            var li = col.querySelectorAll("li");
            for (var k = 0; k < li.length; k++) {
                for (var a = 0; a < bookedAppointmentsArray.length; a++)
                {
                    if (li[k].id == bookedAppointmentsArray[a])
                    {
                        li[k].className = "colorRed booked";
                        break;
                    } else
                    {
                        li[k].className = "colorGreen";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How open are you to 3rd party libraries? This is a piece of cake with jQuery.

Comment: I'm new to javascript and jQuery. Due to my background, I am more comfortable with JavaScript. I sense that I am half way there, I would just like to access the <a> with the <li> using my current code, If you know a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using the query selector to find those `<a>` ?

```
var li = col.querySelectorAll("#tbl_calendar li a");
for (var k = 0; k < li.length; k++) {
    for (var a = 0; a < bookedAppointmentsArray.length; a++)
    {
        if (li[k].id == bookedAppointmentsArray[a])
        {
            li[k].className = "colorRed booked";
            break;
        } else
        {
            li[k].className = "colorGreen";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `table` to access it. Just keep in mind `getElementsByClassName` method:

```
u = document.getElementsByClassName('doctorList');
    for (i = 0; i < u.length; i++){
      l = u[i].getElementsByTagName('li');
      for (j = 0; j < l.length; j++){
        l[j].className = 'red';
      }
    }
```

Checkout this [demo](http://jsbin.com/vadusoveki)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need ancient browsers support, you can do this:

```
var ul = document.querySelector('ul.doctorList');
var li = ul.querySelectorAll('li');

// convert the node list to an array
li = [].slice.call(li);
li.forEach(function(element) {
  if (element.id === '1') {
    var a = element.querySelector('a');
    a.className = 'red';
  }
});
```

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('ul.doctorList');
var li = ul.querySelectorAll('li');

// convert the node list to an array
li = [].slice.call(li);
    li.forEach(function(element) {
      if (element.id === '1') {
        var a = element.querySelector('a');
        a.className = 'red';
      }
    });
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<td style='padding: 0;' bgcolor='#FAFAFA'>
    <ul class='doctorList'>
        <li id='1'><a style='text-decoration: none;'>Curly</a></li>
        <li id='2'>Larry</li>
        <li id='3'><a style='text-decoration: none;'>Moe</a></li>
    </ul>
</td>
```